# Detect if features are next to each other but not overlapping using Turf.js

Tags: leaflet, javascript, turf, edge-detection

I would like to detect if two features are only sharing one or more edges but do not overlap using Turf.js. What I have tried so far is using all the relevant [boolean](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanClockwise) functions of turf. Unfortunately feature1 and feature2 which are only sharing an edge return the same results as feature2 and feature3 which are overlapping. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20wtcg84/1/)

[image]

```js
var map = L.map("map", {
  maxZoom: 20
}).setView([48.18919718488834, 16.30334883928299], 18);

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  maxNativeZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

const feature1 = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          16.30331262946129,
          48.18957269634987
        ],
        [
          16.30341935014826,
          48.18957417438193
        ],
        [
          16.303449844844778,
          48.18920337106684
        ],
        [
          16.30334883928299,
          48.18919718488834
        ],
        [
          16.303340792655945,
          48.18931788530105
        ],
        [
          16.303324699401855,
          48.189450208389815
        ],
        [
          16.30331262946129,
          48.18957269634987
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  }
};

const feature2 = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          16.30331262946129,
          48.18957269634987
        ],
        [
          16.303324699401855,
          48.189450208389815
        ],
        [
          16.303340792655945,
          48.18931788530105
        ],
        [
          16.30334883928299,
          48.18919718488834
        ],
        [
          16.303284466266632,
          48.18919450265372
        ],
        [
          16.30324120664443,
          48.189570444261506
        ],
        [
          16.30331262946129,
          48.18957269634987
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  }
};

const feature3 = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          16.303184844784,
          48.18942325647569
        ],
        [
          16.303184844784,
          48.189347543763205
        ],
        [
          16.303298413188543,
          48.189347543763205
        ],
        [
          16.303298413188543,
          48.18942325647569
        ],
        [
          16.303184844784,
          48.18942325647569
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  }
}

L.geoJson(feature1).addTo(map);
L.geoJson(feature2).addTo(map);
L.geoJson(feature3).addTo(map);

const booleanOverlap12 = turf.booleanOverlap(feature1, feature2);
console.log("booleanOverlap12", booleanOverlap12);

const booleanIntersects12 = turf.booleanIntersects(feature1, feature2);
console.log("booleanIntersects12", booleanIntersects12);

const booleanWithin12 = turf.booleanWithin(feature1, feature2);
console.log("booleanWithin12", booleanWithin12);

//-------
console.log("----------------------")

const booleanOverlap23 = turf.booleanOverlap(feature2, feature3);
console.log("booleanOverlap23", booleanOverlap23);

const booleanIntersects23 = turf.booleanIntersects(feature2, feature3);
console.log("booleanIntersects23", booleanIntersects23);

const booleanWithin23 = turf.booleanWithin(feature2, feature3);
console.log("booleanWithin23", booleanWithin23);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `turf.intersect` and `turf.booleanOverlap` methods to detect if two polygons only have common border but no common area. In such a case `turf.intersect` returns `null` value, but `turf.booleanOverlap` returns `true`.

So function to detect border touch could look something like this:

```
function borderTouch(feature1, feature2) {
  return !turf.intersect(feature1, feature2) && turf.booleanOverlap(feature1, feature2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - works! That should become a turf boolean check IMHO. Need that quite often.